# How to left join unrelated entities?

Tags: jpa, hql, querydsl

When i try to run a query like this:

```
QA A = QA.a;
QB B = QB.b;
...
from(A)
.leftJoin(B).with(B.name.eq(A.nameSomething));
```

(A and B entities are not related)
I'm always getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

I would like to be able to left join unrelated entities using querydsl.
Is it possible at all?
Or the only way is to write a native Oracle query?

Answer (score 4):

Joining unrelated entities is not possible with Querydsl JPA. Querydsl JPA uses JPQL internally and inherit's this restriction.

Comment: so, for entities to be joinable, there must be a relation in both the Java models and the database, right?
If so, this means that if I need to check for existing entries in an n:m join table, I would have to model the entries of the join table in Java, and associate those objects with the 'n'-side of the model. Correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct. alternatively you can use multiple from sources and describe the join conditions in the where part.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to JPA Criteria.
innerJoin, leftOuterJoin are for joining relationships, since that is the only logical thing you would join on in an O-O system.

If instead you want to compare equality of `entity.field` with `entity2.field` (where no FK exists in the database and no relation exists in the classes) then do that in the WHERE clause, just like any filter.

Obviously QueryDSL has its own syntax/rules so if referring to that then this is not JPA